# CEF custom SchemeHandler is not getting POSTed file via Fetch API

Tags: c#, post, fetch-api, cefsharp

I'm trying to save the selected file to a local folder.
Here's some of my code:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input id="menu-upload" name="pdf" type="file" accept="application/pdf">
```

.

```
// JS
document.getElementById('menu-upload').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    fetch("https://pdf/upload", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": file.type
        },
        body: file
    }).then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

.

```
// C# .NET 4.7.2
// CefSharp.WinForms v67.0.0
cef_settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
{
    SchemeName = "https",
    DomainName = "pdf",
    SchemeHandlerFactory = new PdfSchemeHandlerFactory(),
    IsCorsEnabled = true
});

class PdfSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        /* This is where I'm having problems.
            Whenever I inspect `request`,
                it's `Method` is "OPTIONS"
                and PostData is null.
            See linked image. */
        return ResourceHandler.ForErrorMessage("Test", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

[This is what I'm getting](https://postimg.cc/kV0HxzC8).

Since i don't have enough reps to post images, [here's the link](https://postimg.cc/kV0HxzC8)

Are there better ways to pass file data from JS to C#?

Comment: You need to CORS-enable the server the request is being sent to. Your browser is sending a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the POST from your code. Apparently the preflights fails. So the browser stops right there and never tries the POST. To get it working, you need to make the server respond to the OPTIONS request with a 200 OK and the right CORS Access-Control-Allow-\* headers. And you need to make it also send back the right CORS Access-Control-Allow-\* headers for the response to the POST.

Comment: The simplest option is likely to register your scheme handler with a subdomain of your main domain. Basically avoid cors requests all together.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: Actually you can probably add a whitelist entry, see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry.htm

Comment: I added this and I'm still getting an "OPTIONS" request, JS file is in **viewer.pdf.local**: 
`Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry(
                sourceOrigin: "https://upload.pdf.local",
                targetProtocol: "https",
                targetDomain: "pdf.local",
                allowTargetSubdomains: true
            );`

Comment: The method returns a book, make sure it's returning true

Comment: Returns a bool should have been

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve this problem based on the comments in my question:

Instead of feeding `file` directly as the `body` of the request, I placed it inside `FormData`.

```
// JS
var form = new FormData();
form.append("pdf", file);

fetch("https://upload.pdf.local/" + cur_folder, {
    //fetch("http://localhost/api/" + cur_folder, {
    method: "post",
    //mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: form
});
```

Now, the `OPTIONS` request is gone, but the `POST` request still fails without setting the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the `request.ReferrerUrl`.

```
// C# .NET 4.7.2
// CefSharp.WinForms v67.0.0
public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    // .......
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

    var filename = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm") + ".pdf";

    folder = Path.Combine(folder, filename);
    File.Copy(data.File, folder, false);

    var rh = (ResourceHandler)ResourceHandler.ForErrorMessage("Yay!", System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    rh.Headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://viewer.pdf.local";
    return rh;
    // .......
}
```